# Can't load index.php in views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't load index.php file in view folder. The error displayed is

> "Unable to load the requested file: calendar/index.php"

Here is the code

1. controller(Calendar.php):

   ```
    *public function __construct() {
       Parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model("calendar_model");
    }
    public function index()
    {
         $this->load->view("calendar/index.php", array());
    }*
   ```
2. model(Calendar_model.php):

   ```
   *?php
   class Calendar_Model extends CI_Model
   {
   }
   ?>*
   ```
3. view (index.php):

   ```
   *<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Calendar</h1>
           <div id="calendar">
             <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
               });
               });
             </script>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   });
   </script>*
   ```

Comment: is there a sub folder in `views` called `calendar` with a file called `index`? e.g. `application/views/calendar/index`?

Comment: i think thats the problem,,i should remove the calendar,,thank you

Comment: you dont have to remove it, just make a folder called calendar and put the file in it. also it is a good idea not to call views `index.php` it can confuse codeigniter. so maybe `application/views/calendar/calendar.php` and call via `$this->load->view('calendar/calendar');`

Answer (score 0):

Better rename your index.php like V_index.php

for this case remove .php from your code

```
public function __construct() 
{
Parent::__construct();
$this->load->model("calendar_model");
}

public function index()
{
$this->load->view("calendar/index", array());
}
```